# Cant vertically center text inside div

Tags: html, css

I just can't vertically center this text inside my div (red background), I've tried everything but nothing is working, please help! I can't even get my text inside the div whithout using margins/padding for some reason.
I've tried using div, span, p and h1 for the text but nothing worked =(

[image]

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

````
        <div class="headerdiv">
            <div class="backtotop">
                <a class="material-symbols-outlined" href="#" >arrow_upward</a>
                <a class="backtotoptext" href="#">Voltar ao topo</a>
              </div>
        <div class="githubcontainer">
            <a href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios" target="_blank" class="githublink" >//GITHUB LINK</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-title-container">
            <p class="dropdown-title">MENU</p>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">// Trocar Variaveis<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">// Celsius para Farenheit<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">// Farenheit para Celsius<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">// Area Circulo<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">// Par ou Impar<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">// Intervalo entre numeros<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">// Intervalo entre maior e menor de vetor<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">// Maior e menor numero<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">// Paisagem ou retrato<br></a>  
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">// Fizz ou Buzz<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">// String do objeto<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#parimparlimite">// Par ou impar ate limite<br></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>

--------------------------------------------CSS--------------------------------------------

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    background-color: #F6F7EB;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .dropdown-title-container{
    background-color: #DC3318;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .dropdown-title{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    line-height: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    background-color: #F6F7EB;
    padding-right: 15px;
    outline: solid black 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
    border-radius: 0.1vw;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdowna{
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
  }```.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #DC3318;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
.headerdiv{
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.backtotop{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.backtotoptext{
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.55em;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.material-symbols-outlined{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: black;
}
.backtotop:hover .backtotoptext{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.backtotop:hover .material-symbols-outlined{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.githubcontainer{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.githublink{
    color: black;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.githublink:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
````

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: does a github repo with a github pages work?
https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios

Comment: Sorry, SO wants the code in your question, the idea is that your question should be useful to future readers and the external site may disappear making the question worthless. Please read the link I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **add**  `align-items:center;` to `.dropdown-title-container`, and the text will be aligned **vertically**.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code. However, it doesn't show same screen as the image you posted,

so I can not say exactly. have you try 'align-items: center;'

```
.dropdown-title-container{
    background-color: #DC3318;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to do something simple much harder than needed.

in your CSS file try to put a tag `align-items: center` inside `.dropdown-title-container`.

like this:

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown-title-container{
  background-color: #DC3318;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.dropdown-title{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  padding-right: 15px;
  outline: solid black 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
  border-radius: 0.1vw;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdowna{
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  margin-left: 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
.sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #DC3318;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
.headerdiv{
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.backtotop{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.backtotoptext{
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.55em;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.material-symbols-outlined{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: black;
}
.backtotop:hover .backtotoptext{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.backtotop:hover .material-symbols-outlined{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.githubcontainer{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.githublink{
    color: black;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.githublink:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="headerdiv">
      <div class="backtotop">
        <a class="material-symbols-outlined" href="#">arrow_upward</a>
        <a class="backtotoptext" href="#">Voltar ao topo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="githubcontainer">
        <a
          href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios"
          target="_blank"
          class="githublink"
          >//GITHUB LINK</a
        >
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-title-container">
          <p class="dropdown-title">MENU</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis"
            >// Trocar Variaveis<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit"
            >// Celsius para Farenheit<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius"
            >// Farenheit para Celsius<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">// Area Circulo<br /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">// Par ou Impar<br /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo"
            >// Intervalo entre numeros<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor"
            >// Intervalo entre maior e menor de vetor<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor"
            >// Maior e menor numero<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato"
            >// Paisagem ou retrato<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">// Fizz ou Buzz<br /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject"
            >// String do objeto<br
          /></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#parimparlimite"
            >// Par ou impar ate limite<br
          /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

:D

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) should help you in the future.